# Upload file from url via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I have the following problem:

I have a web page that show 2 images, when user selects one of these pictures, a javascript function must take this picture and send it to another server (with standard multipart post)

I have only url of image, so first I download it via javascript, then I try to send it to server, follow my code

```
function sendImgFromUrl(url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                var file = event.target.result;

                var resReq = new FormData();
                resReq.append("service_name",service_name);
                resReq.append("file",file); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: "myurl", 
                    data: resReq,
                    type: 'POST',
                    processData: false, 
                    contentType: false, 
                    async: false,
                    complete : function(response){
                         console.log(response);
                    }

                 }); 
            }
            reader.readAsBinaryString(this.response);

        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

What I obtain is a call with an Object instead of (image)File

```
-----------------------------201521280032720 
Content-Disposition: form-data;      
name="file" [object FileReader] 
-----------------------------201521280032720
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YEA!
I found a solution

I used `reader.result` and i putted it into a blob object

```
function sendImgFromUrl(url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function(){
                file = new Blob([reader.result], { type: "image/png" });

                var resReq = new FormData();
                resReq.append("service_name",service_name);
                resReq.append("file",file); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: "myurl", 
                    data: resReq,
                    type: 'POST',
                    processData: false, 
                    contentType: false, 
                    async: false,
                    complete : function(response){
                         console.log(response);
                    }

                 }); 
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.response);

        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stuff these as the ajax request options as well:

```
cache: false,
contentType: false,
mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
processData: false,
method: 'POST'
```

contentType, mimeType and processData -options are quite important.

processData: false tells jQuery not to screw the data up and send it as is, while contentType: false lets jQuery put the right content type automatically. mimeType might be important as well since you are sending form data, which is multipart because of the image.

Comment: ops, it's my fault, i cutted a modified code (one of thousand test that i tried)...I edited the post with real code. I tried to add `mimetype` and `cache` but result it's the same -_-